# How to add values from one dictionary to another based on matching keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have two dictionaries with matching keys and different values. I want to add the values of a to b.

Some keys are in dictionary a but not b. I want to skip over these.

```
a = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d"}
b = {1:"e", 2:"f", 3:"g"}



for k, v in a.items():
    if k in b.keys():
        list(b).append(v)
    else: print 'Could not locate key', k
```

I would like the output to be
    b = {1: ["e", "a"], 2: ["b", "f"], 3: ["g","c"]}

Instead the values aren't appending. I've also tried using brackets around the v, which returns

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What about keys that are in `b` but not in `a`? Do you want the values of those keys converted to lists?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want... I used strings for the original values but will still work with lists.

```
>>> a = {"1":"a", "2":"b", "3": "c", "4":"d"}
>>> b = {"1":"e", "2":"f", "3":"g"}
>>> for k, v in a.items():
...     if k in b:
...         b[k] = [a[k], b[k]]
... 
>>> b
{'1': ['a', 'e'], '2': ['b', 'f'], '3': ['c', 'g']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you want?

```
a = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d"}
b = {1:"e", 2:"f", 3:"g"}
c={}

keys = set(list(a.keys())+list(b.keys()))

for key in keys:
    items = []
    items += [a[key]] if key in a else []
    items += [b[key]] if key in b else []
    c[key]=items
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d"}
    b = {1:"e", 2:"f", 3:"g"}

    for k, v in a.items():
        if k in b.keys():
            b[k] = [v,b[k]]
        else: print('Could not locate key', k)
    print(b)

output :
Could not locate key 4
{1: ['a', 'e'], 2: ['b', 'f'], 3: ['c', 'g']}
```

use b[k] = [v,b[k]] instead of list(b).append(v)

list(b).append(v) means you are creating a list of keys of dictionary b and then appending v to that

b[k] = [v,b[k]] means create a list of values of dict a and b for key k and assign to dictionary b at key k